# ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE when exporting/setting Private Key using code Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1, 'hex')

Tags: web3js

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined
```

From the following line of code I believe:

```
var privateKey1 = new Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1, 'hex')
```

But when I just put in my actual key:

```
var privateKey1 = new Buffer.from(' my actual key ', 'hex')
```

It does in fact work, using:

```
set PRIVATE_KEY_1 = 'my actual key'
```

As export didn't work on my system, removing the `0x` from the front.

And when I type `set` in node.js, I can see that it is stored:

```
PRIVATE_KEY_1 = 'my actual key'
```

Without the `0x` on front

How might I fix this?

Comment: How about `new Buffer.from('0x' + process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1, 'hex')`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I couldnt get the above suggestion to work but II found I could use use 'export' instead of 'set' in Bash to get it to work properly.